# Iterating through a dict in python is not yielding desired results

Tags: python

I am trying to build a deck of cards in python but I am trying to store all the info in a dictionary. I need to store the card name (i.e., 2, 4, 'K' for king, 'J' for jack etc), the value the card is worth in black jack (i.e., 2 is worth 2, 'A' for ace is worth 1 or 11 depending on the scenario), and the number of that particular card remaining int the deck. However when I write my python code, I realize that all of the card values are equal to 8. Now, I know that something is not right but I am new to python and I am trying to understand why am I yielding such devastating results

Code Sample:

```
class Card(object):

    def __init__(self, list):
        self.deck_list = list
        self.construct_deck()

    def construct_deck(self):
        #Here we created a dictionary from the list keys
        self.deck = dict.fromkeys(self.deck_list, {'total': 4, 'value': 0})
        self.keys = self.deck.keys()

        for key in self.keys:
            try:
                value = int(key)

            except:

                if key != 'A':
                    value = 10
                else:
                    value = [1,11]

            finally:
                self.deck[key]['value'] = value


    def shuffle_deck(self):
        pass

l = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']

bj = Card(l)

print bj.deck
```

The code should do the following:

- If the key was able to be converted to an int then it must have been 2-10 and the value is then set to the integer version of the key
- However if the try block failed, the value must be a char. The value of all the pretty cards (jack, king and queen) are all ten, so if the key is either 'J', 'K' or 'Q' the value should be set to ten, other it should be set to the list [1,11]. Finally the finally should assign the value to the value corresponding to that key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your use of `dict.fromkeys()` with the value dict as the default value. This sets the *same* dictionary as the value for all of the keys, so if you update one, they are all updated.

A better solution would be set an empty dict, then just iterate through the deck_list. (Also note that `self.keys` is the same as `self.deck_list`; no point having both).

Also, you should always avoid a blank except; catch the errors you are expecting, which in this case is only ValueError. Also this isn't really a good use of `finally`; just remove that and unindent the block.

```
self.deck = {}

for key in self.deck_list:

    try:
        value = int(key)
    except ValueError:
        if key == 'A':
            value = [1,11]
        else:
            value = 10

    self.deck[key] = {'total': 4, 'value': value}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I saw where I went wrong and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Your initial "fromkeys" statement sets all values to the same dict object. You can demonstrate this with:

```
print bj.deck['3'] is bj.deck['4']
# prints True
```

Since the values are all references to the same dict, the final key you parse, "8", becomes the "value" for the dict.

You can fix this by creating a separate dict for each key:

```
self.deck = dict([(k, {'total': 4, 'value': 0}) 
                 for k in self.deck_list])
```